# Files disappearing in Ubuntu

Tags: hidden-files

I have a lot of music in my hard drive and some times they disappear. In my previous Ubuntu installation, this was happening very much. I did I fresh install a few days ago (not because of this) and now this returned: I noticed that in Rhythmbox a few songs were missing. After I opened my music folder and searched for them in Nautilus, they reappeared again in Rhythmbox.

It makes me wonder if something are happening to the search index. I don't think the hard drive is failing, because this computer is still one-year-old.

In the previous installation, files were missing in Nautilus. Sometimes I needed to press F5 for them to appear.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ubuntu do you have? Can you see your music files through console?

```
ls -l ~/Music/
```

Did you try alternative file manager and music player (mocp for example)? If not I would recommend to check this first. 
Few words about MOC. MOC - Music On Console, official [page](https://moc.daper.net/), 
`sudo apt-get install moc` - to install it.